# Trigger inputing information about action in table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I created table to store informations about time of any update, insert or delete data in one of tables.

```
CREATE TABLE dept_changes ( data DATE, action VARCHAR2(16) );
```

Now I want to create trigger inputing the data to table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dept_changes_trig AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT OR DELETE ON departments
DECLARE
    action VARCHAR2(16);
BEGIN
    IF UPDATING THEN
        action:='upd';
    END IF;
    IF INSERTING THEN
        action:='ins';
    END IF;
    IF DELETING THEN
        action:='del';
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO DEPT_CHANGES (SYSDATE, action);
END;
```

I got 2 errors in line 12 (END IF of DELETING condition statement).

```
Error(12,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(12,46): PL/SQL: ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword
```

I don't understand, what `VALUES` am I missing? What the trigger needs to work properly?

Comment: look at line 12, column 46. Your INSERT statement is missing the VALUES keyword. INSERT INTO table VALUES ( values )

Comment: My thanks, it works. I didn't understend the error, and my tutorial missed the VALUES keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **values** keyword

INSERT INTO DEPT_CHANGES **VALUES** (SYSDATE, action);

[Insert Examples](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9014.htm#i2145081)